# JavaScript - Trying to disable all radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

When a button is pressed i'm trying to get all the radio buttons to disable. 
So far i have set ALL of the ids on the radio buttons to "1"

HTML code:

```
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Bob <br>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Jim <br>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="correct"> Callum <br>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
```

However when I test this out it only disables 1 radio button and not all of them. Is there a way to disable them all doing it like i've tried?

Thanks

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you're misusing them. You could use something else to group the `<input>`s together, e.g. a class or a containing `<div>`.

Comment: How can i do this using class?

Comment: With what part of using a class are you having trouble?

Comment: BIffen is right: an ID in a HTML file must be uniqe. Beyond that it must beginn with a letter, upper or lower case doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Bob <br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Jim <br>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="correct"> Callum <br>
```

Javascript with class:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is ok, but isn't adding ``class="checkbox"`` a little redundant in this case. You could also do ``document.getElementsByTagName("input")`` and spare the class. Depending on the particular case any of these solutions can be favored.

Comment: Of course it is. But it's only for example so he can select somehow only checkboxes that he want to disable.

Comment: It works. Just iterate by class or by tag name or whatever you want, abnd the the disabled = true do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.

HTML:

```
<form if="myForm">
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Bob <br>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Jim <br>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="correct"> Callum <br>
</form>
```

JS ES6:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

form.Q1.forEach(cb => (cb.disabled = true));
```

JS Vanilla:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#myForm');

form.Q1.forEach(function(cb) {
   cb.disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Since Id's are unique, you shouldnot give same Id to all the buttons, Rather give all the buttons a same class. And then you can run for loop:

```
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("your class name");
for(var i=0;i<radioButtons.length;i++) {
   radioButtons[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: it is redundant using a class, it is better with the name property

Answer (score -3):

Use this instead:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Bob <br>
<input id="2" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="incorrect"> Jim <br>
<input id="3" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="correct"> Callum <br>
```

Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
      if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
      {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: This would have the side effect of disabling every checkbox on the entire page, however.

Comment: @Dremmi, read the OP's header, it reads : "Trying to disable all radio buttons". Why do you find pleasure in downvoting?

Comment: @Drenmi: The OP should decide which solution is more appropriate in his very particular case. And again: id must beginn with a letter, otherwise not a valid HTML.